# Icecast server with AWS S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, icecast

I'm currently running an icecast server for streaming audio on an EC2 Instance.

Currently all my .mp3 files are stored on the EC2 instance and I want to move them to AWS S3 for storage. So far I've been able to find scripts that will [update the playlist](https://mediarealm.com.au/articles/icecast-automatically-updating-configuration-from-s3/) but will not make the server request external sources.

Is it possible to setup this architecture? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about mounting the S3 bucket as a directory and just using that?

- https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse / https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Fuse-Over-Amazon
- https://github.com/russross/s3fslite

As you only read the files, this should be without major issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used s3fs at it worked like a charm!

Comment: I've used this exact method, and it does work reasonably well.  Beware though, you need to handle the cases when it stops working correctly.  The FUSE driver will cache directory listings, but sometimes the resources will be unavailable and just hang.  You have this same problem with any non-local FS, just be sure to handle it on the source end.