# How to best stream audio from AWS to mobile app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, streaming

I've seen several solutions to streaming audio files from AWS S3 to websites. However, as far as I know S3 uses HTTP and not UDP. Is streaming < 10 mb audio files via S3 and HTTP the "best" or "right" solution when using AWS? Or is there a service or way that is perhaps better suited for this?

I've tried Googling it, but I haven't been able to find anything offical, and most people seem to use AWS S3 and pre-signed links for it.

Does anyone have experience with just using AWS S3 and pre-signed links in any production application?

Comment: You have options for this use case. One option is to build an Android App using the new AWS SDK for Kotlin in Android Studio. Then use the MediaPlayer API to play an MP3 file that is located in an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: @smac2020 Do you know of similar solutions in React Native?

Answer (score 2):

There's no native, cost-effective option that I'm aware of from AWS.

One common option seems to be Icecast running on EC2, possibly using [Liquidsoap](https://www.liquidsoap.info/doc-1.3.3/quick_start.html).

See:

- [Looking to built an audio streaming service](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/be24ch/aws_expertise_needed_looking_to_built_an_audio/)
- [Icecast server with media hosted in S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655524/icecast-server-with-aws-s3-files)
- [Wowza streaming engine](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-nqvjwn3d6ouqa)